# Can you attach other sensors in place of AD8232 electrode probes?

Tags: heartbeat

Maybe your knowledge and experience can expedite my project :)

As AD8232 is such a well designed and compact circuit, and as (from my observations), whatever data you input into the probes it will do it's best to output a heart beat -- I was wondering is it possible to attach the voltage readings of another sensor or component in place of any (or any specific one of the three) electrode probes the AD8232 is designed with? (or buying/building another multimodal photoplethysmogram/electrocardiogram board is necessary?)

My wish would be to combine the ECG component (the voltages produced by muscle contractions detectable on the interface of the skin) with the optical heart beat monitor sensors, to:

1. Reduce the impact of electromagnetic noise
2. Improve readings during movement

I you sway towards it being possible, than my next two follow up questions would be:

1. Does it matter in place of which of the three probes I attach it to? Or does the AD8232 chip infer how it processes the voltage from a single probe dynamically, irregardless of which one it is actually?
2. Does the signal needs to be filtered and conditioned, coming from, for example the MAX30102 PPG board or can I just connect a light sensing diode and the AD8232 board will be capable of discerning the heartbeat from it alone?

Thank you

[I'm interested only in solutions which don't require a microprocessor]